# After resuming from suspend, my mouse pointer is confined to a small rectangle in the middle of the screen

Tags: debian, x11, xfce, thinkpad

On my Thinkpad T460 running XFCE on Debian Bullseye (11.7), when resuming from suspend, sometimes my mouse pointer is restricted to a small rectangle in the middle of the screen, and my keyboard no longer works.

As a workaround, restarting lightdm makes the mouse and keyboard work normally again. I've tried disabling TLP, but that didn't help.

How can I ensure that the keyboard and mouse work reliably after resuming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was xscreensaver.  For some reason when resuming from sleep, xscreensaver had my mouse/keyboard restricted to the screen region that is normally owned by the "unlock with password" dialog.  When I kill xscreensaver, I get my mouse and keyboard back.